# Notifications on Wordpress Website

Tags: plugins, posts, notifications

I am working on a wordpress website where users can register and post things that they would like to promote or anything that they like to post. Now how can i enable notifications for the user whenever someone comments on their posts or like their posts or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [BuddyPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/). It covers majority of your functionality.

Or you can go with custom approach using Custom PHP script and AJAX with custom tables created in Database. Here is a link to such tutorial.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/real-time-php-notification-system/

---

**EDIT :** I don't know what approach you are following. But considering you are using Wordpress Post and Comments.
Create a DB table for storing notifications. [Click here](https://github.com/Vheissu/Open-Source-Database-Schemas/blob/master/vheissu-notifications-schema.md) for a DB schema

Try using [**'comment_post'**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post) action. And in that function you can get `POST_ID` based on `COMMENT_ID` & then you can get `POST_AUTHOR` based on `POST_ID`. Create entry in the notification table mentioned above. You can also send him/her an email as well.

Now when a User logs in. you can fetch entries from Notification table and show it on your web page.

This is just the approach i gave you. For proper execution you can follow the blog post mentioned above and combine it with this approach.

Comment: I just need notification for comments that all. rest i have account registration posting and stuff.

Comment: Updated the answer